# How do you store the values from a Redux-Form in a different format?

Tags: javascript, forms, redux, react-redux, redux-form

So this a two part question regarding this Redux-Form.

First is the Field for the type="date". Information gets entered as MM/DD/YYYY, but once its submitted it is stored as YYYY/MM/DD. So when a user views that info, it displays like that. How do I change that displayed format back to MM/DD/YYYY?

Second is for the Field for the type="time". It is entered as 12hr format with the AM/PM selector but its stored as 24hr time. When the user sees that info how do I display it as 12hr time and not 24hr?

Thank you.

```
import React from 'react'; 
import {connect} from 'react-redux'; 
import {Field, reduxForm, focus} from 'redux-form'; 
import {required, nonEmpty} from '../validators'; 
import Input from './input'; 
import {postDate} from '../actions/protected-data'; 
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

export class AddDateForm extends React.Component {
    onSubmit(values) {
        values.username = this.props.username;
        this.props.dispatch(postDate(values));
        this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form className="my-2 p-3 text-center bg-dark" onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(values =>this.onSubmit(values))}>
                <label htmlFor="park">Park Name</label>
                <div>
                <Field
                    component={Input} 
                    type="text" 
                    name="park" 
                    validate={[required, nonEmpty]}
                    placeholder="Park Name"
                />
                </div>
                <label htmlFor="date">Date</label>
                <Field 
                    component={Input} 
                    type="date" 
                    name="date" 
                    validate={[required, nonEmpty]}
                />
                <label htmlFor="startTime">Start Time</label>
                <Field 
                    component={Input} 
                    type="time" 
                    name="startTime"
                    validate={[required, nonEmpty]}
                />
                <label htmlFor="endTime">End Time</label>
                <Field 
                    component={Input}
                    type="time"
                    name="endTime"
                    validate={[required, nonEmpty]}
                />
                <button 
                    className="button mt-3 mx-auto btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" 
                    type="submit" 
                    disabled={this.props.pristine || this.props.submitting}>
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        );
    } }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    username: state.auth.currentUser.username });

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'add',
    onSubmitFail: (errors, dispatch) =>
        dispatch(focus('contact', Object.keys(errors)[0])) }(withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(AddDateForm)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `format` (there is also `parse`) function prop. [Field API](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/field.md/)

Comment: I was reading that page earlier but it didn't show any examples of how exactly to do it. Do you know how to implement the format prop in this particular form? Or do you have any links to examples?